# MSAL Issues when integrating Azure AD Authentication and Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-api

I have enabled authentication for azure ad by following some sample apps from MS as shown below. I then use the authorize statements below as well so my application should be locked down unless the user is authenticated. My issue in my testing environment is if i restart IIS express then when it starts back up I am not required to log back in if the browser is still open. I can openly navigate my application but when any function related to MS Graph is called it fails with error: ErrorCode: user_null Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call. So its as if my application thinks I am still authorized but really I am not because the MS Graph api call fails because of token related issues. If I force myself to logout then log back in everything works. For my live site if a user is inactive for some time but the browser is left open this same issue occurs and they are not forced to relogin so these issues again can happen until they force logout and re log back in. What have I setup wrong or need to add to force relogin before these issues arise? Or can I keep the token working without forcing the user to relogin?

```
    // Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Login");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/files");
});

//authentication pipline
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
var initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
                {
                    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        //Tap into this event to add a UserID Claim to a new HttpContext identity
                        OnTokenValidated = context =>
                        {
                            //This query returns the UserID from the DB by sending the email address in the claim from Azure AD
                            string query = "select dbo.A2F_0013_ReturnUserIDForEmail(@Email) as UserID";
                            string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:DBContext");
                            string signInEmailAddress = context.Principal.FindFirstValue("preferred_username");

                            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                            {
                                var queryResult = connection.QueryFirst(query, new { Email = signInEmailAddress });

                                var claims = new List<Claim>
                                {
                                    new Claim("UserID", queryResult.UserID.ToString())
                                };

                                var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

                                context.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                    };

                })
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

//Add Transient Services
builder.Services.AddTransient<IOneDrive, OneDrive>();

builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Then in all of my controllers I use:

```
[AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
```

Adding

```
var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(initialScopes);
```

before my graph api call fixes my issue. However, I feel as though I shouldnt need to call this everytime but only if the token expires. So is there a way to check if the token expires?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that worked for me. One was trying to get a token manually if an error occurred using the following:

```
var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(initialScopes);
```

The other solution that seemed to work the same was to add the following catch as well:

```
                    try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{svcex}");
                    string claimChallenge = WwwAuthenticateParameters.GetClaimChallengeFromResponseHeaders(svcex.ResponseHeaders);
                    _consentHandler.ChallengeUser(initialScopes, claimChallenge);
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    _consentHandler.HandleException(ex2);
                }
```

I do not know enough about what consent handler does to provide more info on why this works but will update my answer once I do.